# c# program , get notification when user switch between applications

Tags: c#

Want to hook my c# code to some windows API so that I can get a notification when the logged in user switch between windows(programs) open on the desktop

- Event/Notification:- when user switch between applications. For example we have notepad,work,excel,outlook,IE open in parallel on the same desktop.

Is polling the only way ? say every 5 mins- for current  active window on desktop. that will not be very efficient.

I want to run this program on windowsXP.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointer , this should help. Do you have some refrence to how I can call this from c# ?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html

 It has the required mappings for what you want I think